# Can we minimize the no of transistor by using Transistor connected as a diode

Tags: transistors, diodes

I need to know the advantage and limitation of a transistor connected as diode.

In a paper which i ref..its existing level shifter circuit consist of 17 no of transistor(CMOS) and this shift the voltage signal from 5V to 10V.

In its proposed work the circuit consist of only 8 no of transistor(CMOS) that connected as a diode and it shift the voltage from 5V to 30V.

How it is possible with transistor as a diode? Wont it create any junction breakdown problem?

Comment: What is the "no" of a transistor?  Your title makes no sense.

Comment: I believe that they mean 'no.' as in number.

Comment: @scld: Then -1 for being sloppy and trying to save 50 ms at the expense of everyone trying to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a 'diode-connected' MOSFET is taken to be a MOSFET with the gate and drain connected, analogous to a diode-connected BJT with base and collector connected.

In US6960946 a level shifter design is disclosed that uses a diode-connected MOSFET (N21) as a load. The \$V_{GS}\$ breakdown voltage (it's not a 'junction') must exceed the higher supply voltage (when N24 turns on), however, so I don't think it would typically be all that suitable for a 30V supply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the number of components is trivial if the transistor is expected to work as effectively as a diode in (say) a power supply circuit. Consider a bridge rectifier. It has four pins and a reverse voltage capability of possibly hundreds of volts. Most BJTs can't handle more than 10v across the base emitter junction in reverse. The bridge may be rated at 1A forward current but finding a transistor that can take more than 1A through the base will be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard for me to interpret, especially talking about diode-connected transistors in the context of CMOS. But you find diode-connected BJTs (not CMOS) in every current mirror or bandgap reference, for example. Since most opamps using BJTs also need current source/sinks, they are also found there. They are found in SCRs. Etc. The MOSFET structures will often "appear" similar. But they aren't exactly "diode-connected."

Your question isn't clear, though.